# C++ Bubble sort dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I wrote a bubble sorting algorithm which sorts a dynamically allocated array using string comparison.

Here is my code:

```
void AddressBook::bubble_sort_address_book(){
    bool swapped = true;
    while(swapped){
        swapped = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < noOfEmployees; i++){
            if(employees[i].combined_name() > employees[i+1].combined_name()){
                Employee temp_employee = employees[i+1];
                employees[i+1] = employees[i];
                employees[i] = temp_employee;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is pretty obvious, yet I can not seem to figure out how to solve it: The code sometimes fails on the line (in an undefined manner) :

```
Employee temp_employee = employees[i+1]
```

Its pretty obvious because if `i` is equal to the end of the array, accessing memory with `i+1` results in undefined behaviour. However, if I stop the for loop with `noOfEmployees-1`, this does not happen but the first element is never sorted (obviously).

How can I implement bubble sort properly? It seems as such a trivial task. Am I missing something?

Comment: `i < noOfEmployees` really must be `i < noOfEmployees-1`. And the first element gets sorted this way.

Comment: but the first elements always remains unsorted this way, at least in my code

Comment: There is also `std::sort`, which would also be more efficient than the bubble sort you're using.

Comment: Following the exchange, add `swapped = true;` as you just swapped.

Comment: Yes, but we are not allowed to use anything except for std::string, not even std::vector! (It's a university assignment)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks, forgot that. Still does not work though

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code following my changes. Then there must be something wrong in your `>` operator.

Comment: Oh, yes doing `i < noOfEmployees-1` with `swapped = true` works like a charm! However, is not `swapped` just used for optimisation purposes, should not it be working without it?

Comment: If you follow the logic in your head or with pen and paper you will find that `swapped` is necessary.

Comment: Yeah you are right, thanks! Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @BalázsVincze are you allowed to define extra functions? e.g. `bool operator <(Employee const &, Employee const &)` and `void swap(Employee &, Employee &)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simplified version in pure C works fine:

```
int employees[10]= {3,1,7,6,9,7,1,0,2,6};
int noOfEmployees= 10;

void bubble_sort_address_book(void){
    bool swapped = true;
    int i;
    while(swapped){
        swapped = false;
        for(i = 0; i < noOfEmployees-1; i++){
            if(employees[i] > employees[i+1]){
                int temp_employee = employees[i+1];
                employees[i+1] = employees[i];
                employees[i] = temp_employee;
                swapped= true;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    bubble_sort_address_book();
    for (i=0; i<noOfEmployees; i++) {
        printf("emp %d= %d\n", i, employees[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you request, the function of variable `swapped` is to indicate that following a complete pass through the array no swap occurred and so it indicates the array is now sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an explicit bound on the outer loop.

You should also split things out into smaller functions.

```
bool operator <(Employee const & lhs, Employee const & rhs) {
    return lhs.combined_name() < rhs.combined_name();
}

// a.k.a. std::swap
void swap(Employee & lhs, Employee & rhs) {
    Employee temp(static_cast<Employee&&>(lhs)); // a.k.a. std::move
    lhs = static_cast<Employee&&>(rhs);
    rhs = static_cast<Employee&&>(temp);
}

void bubble_sort_impl(Employee * begin, Employee * end) {
    for (; end != begin; --end) {
        for (Employee * it = begin; it+1 != end; ++it) {
            if (*(it+1) < *it) {
                swap(*it, *(it+1));
            }
        }
    }
}

// do we really need "bubble_" or "_address_book" in this name?
void AddressBook::bubble_sort_address_book() {
    bubble_sort_impl(employees, employees + noOfEmployees);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int employees[10] = { 3,1,7,6,9,7,1,0,2,6 };


void bubble_sort_address_book(void) {
    bool swapped = true;
    int i;
    int noOfEmployees = 10;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        for (i = 1; i <= noOfEmployees ; i++) {
            if (employees[i] > employees[i - 1]) {
                int temp_employee = employees[i - 1];
                employees[i - 1] = employees[i];
                employees[i] = temp_employee;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    int noOfEmployees = 10;
    bubble_sort_address_book();
    for (i = 0; i<noOfEmployees; i++) {
        printf("emp %d= %d\n", i, employees[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```